# Selected value dropdownbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

With this script I fill the dropdownbox dynamicly:

```
function loadDropbox(boxName,checkBox,selected){
    var htmlStr="";
    var searchXML = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
    searchXML = getXML("WEBDRPO0;?BDR="+bdr+"&TYPE_ART=D");
    var nodeList = xmlDoc1.documentElement.selectNodes("//box[@name='"+boxName+"']");
        try{
    for(i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++){
    var vals = ""+nodeList[i].firstChild.nodeValue+"";
    vals = vals.split("~");
    for(i=0;i<vals.length;i++){
    if(checkBox=='1'){
        htmlStr+="<br /><label><input type=checkbox name='aanwezigheid' id='aanwezigheid' value="+vals[i]+" id="+vals[i]+"/>"+vals[i]+"</label><br/>";
    }else if(selected == vals[i]){
        htmlStr+="<option selected='selected'>"+vals[i]+"</option>";
    }else{
        htmlStr+="<option>"+vals[i]+"</option>";
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    catch(e){}
    return htmlStr;
}
```

This is the HTML result:

```
<select id="year" name="year">
  <option>--Make Choice--</option>
  <option>1980 - 1990</option>
  <option>1990 - 2000</option>
  <option>2000 - 2010</option>
  <option>2010 - later</option>
</select>
```

With this Javascript I would make the "2010 - later" value the seleceted value.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("year").value = "2010 - later";
</script>
```

It works fine in Firefox, but it don't work in IE9.
What am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Freexel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `value` attribute for the `option`.

***Eg:***

```
<option value="2010 - later">2010 - later</option>
```

***Update:***
According your code, it should be:

```
htmlStr+='<option value="'+vals[i]+'" selected="selected">'+vals[i]+'</option>';
```

And

```
htmlStr+='<option value="'+vals[i]+'">'+vals[i]+'</option>';
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is static, the selected value is different each time. That's the reason why I must use javascript.

Comment: Why this is static, I mean when you create the select, you should set the value attribute for the option, no matter it is static or dynamic.

Comment: I have update my question :) Maybe you understand my question better now :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want...

Working in FF and IE both...

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="year" name="year">
  <option>--Make Choice--</option>
  <option selected value="1980 - 1990">1980 - 1990</option>
  <option value="1990 - 2000">1990 - 2000</option>
  <option value="2000 - 2010">2000 - 2010</option>
  <option value="2010 - later">2010 - later</option>
</select>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("year").value = "2010 - later";
</script>
</html>
```

Also your `htmlStr+="<option>"+vals[i]+"</option>";` should not be `htmlStr+="<option value='" +vals[i]+ "'>"+vals[i]+"</option>";`

### Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, I know that. But I must use Javascript, because I'm filling the box dynamicly, using XML.